# As3 Memory Leak? - How to garbage collect a newed as3 Sound Object from memory?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, audio

It looks like simply newing an as3 Sound Object, and setting its reference back to null will create a memory leak, wether or not it has been used to play a SoundChannel on it.

For example, using next text code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.system.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.system.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = "../data/SongScene8.mp3")] protected var SongScene8:Class;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            System.gc();
            trace("Before");
            trace(System.totalMemory);
            trace("_________________")

            var sound:Sound = new SongScene8();
            System.gc();
            trace("After new");
            trace(System.totalMemory);
            trace("_________________")

            sound = null;
            System.gc();
            trace("After null");
            trace(System.totalMemory);
        }
    }

}
```

The output is:

Before
3461120

---

After new
3604480

---

After null
3604480

Even if the gc runs a thousand times after, the last value remains.

So, wether or not a soundchannel is played on it, it looks like the Sound Object
cannot be removed from memory.

Please say I'm wrong and tell me why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force Garbage Collection in AS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192373/force-garbage-collection-in-as3)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a moment to breathe, the memory might not get released instantly.

```
sound = null;
System.gc();

trace('After null');
trace('Instantly: ' + System.totalMemory);
setTimeout(function():void
{
    trace('2 seconds later: ' + System.totalMemory);
}, 
2000);
```

Also note that [`System.gc`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc%28%29) works only in AIR and the debugger versions of Flash Player!

According to [an old article from gskinner](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/08/as3_resource_ma_2.html), there's a trick to force an immediate release, calling [`LocalConnection.connect`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html#close%28%29) two times. Not sure how reliable that is, but a quick test shows that it seems to work:

```
sound = null;

try {
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
} catch (e:*) {}

trace('After null');
trace('Instantly: ' + System.totalMemory);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the LocalConnection trick, yet it didn't appear to have effect, in this case.
Calling System.gc on frame events for thousand of frames neither.
I posted the same question at the Adobe As3 forum:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4814155#4814155
So far, it seems safe to conclude that 
1 The problem is not manifesting itself when testing on Iphone.
2 Either there's a non-repetive leak using the desktop,
  or there's none, but due to relaxed memory constraints on the desktop, its OS never releases them.